# PHP-Unable get values from $_SESSION, error msg is Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Tags: php, mysqli, session-variables

First let me explain my code.
It comprises of three php files.

1. inc_fn_header_and_menu.php,  contains the HTML and CSS header details
   and it initializes the session via session_start();
2. This  is later included in project_status.php] .
3. In project_status.php] , I have included another file
   project_status_app.php which contains a HTML form.

**project_status.php:**

```
<?php
     include 'inc_fn_header_and_menu.php';
    function includeFile($file,$variable) {
        $var = $variable;
        include($file);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!="") {
        $pid    = $_GET['id'];
        $_SESSION['pidForApproval'] = $_GET['id'];
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE pid ='.'\''.$pid.'\'';
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$queryToRetrievePP) or die("There are no records to display ... \n". 
        mysqli_error());
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $status = $row['status'];
    ?>
```

**project_status_app.php**

In project_status_app.php I am attempting to retrieve pidForApproval from the $_SESSION array.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   include '../../inc/fastlogin.php';      
   $sql = "UPDATE pp SET customer_purchase_remarks ='{$_POST['remarkstxt']}' WHERE pp.pid='{$_SESSION['pidForApproval']}'"; 
   $result = mysqli_query ( $fastdb, $sql ) ;
       if (mysqli_affected_rows($fastdb) != 1) { 
              $_SESSION['err_cpa_rmks'] = "<p>Error while updating WHERE id='{$_SESSION['pidForApproval']}'</p>";                                   
           } else { 
              $_SESSION['suc_cpa_rmks'] = "<p>Records was updated successfully.</p>";
           }
           header ("location: project_status.php?id="$_SESSION['pidForApproval']);
           exit();
          }                              
    ?>
```

When I load  project_status.php,  project_status_app.php is supposed to display the form. Once the user fills in the form the and the submit button has been pressed, the UPDATE statement is supposed to run and then it is supposed to navigate back to project_status.php?id=FA142. But the update is failing and the when the project_status.php is loaded back, the url looks like this http://localhost/fast/project_status.php?id= . The id is empty. It is supposed to be something like this http://localhost/fast/project_status.php?id=FA142. With the id being populated at the

```
header ("location: project_status.php?id=".$_SESSION['pidForApproval']);
```

I suspected that my $_SESSION['pidForApproval'] is not being populated in project_status.php but I echoed back $_SESSION['pidForApproval'] in that file itself and I can see it is being populated. Hence, I suspect that the $_SESSION['pidForApproval'] is not being passed to project_status_app.php. I have already attempted to include session_start(); clause in project_status_app.php but that gives an error, stating that the session has already started, in inc_fn_header_and_menu.php. Can someone help me as to why the $_SESSION['pidForApproval'] is *not being passed on to the project_status_app.php* file. Thank you.

Comment: In your code, `header ("location: project_status.php?id="$_SESSION['pidForApproval']);` is missing the `.` before `$_SESSION`.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.